# Is there a stroke order for any of the Klingon alphabets?

Tags: writing-systems, klingon

Is there an order in which you write the strokes making up a letter belonging to the Klingon alphabet (apart from the Latin alphabet)?

Are letters from Klingon alphabets intended to be written manually, as opposed to solely being printed?

I looked at [Klingon alphabets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_alphabets) and [pIqaD](http://www.klingonwiki.net/En/PIqaD) but neither had information about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been stroke ordering proposals by fans devising handwriting of pIqaD. One is http://klingonska.org/writing/examples/pic/zrajm-piqad.jpg , from  Zrajm of Klingonska Akademien: http://klingonska.org/piqad/. Another had been proposed by the late Glen Proechel's group:

> Interstellar Language School (lead by Glen F. Proechel) has published “An Alien Writing System Primer” explaining how to write pI­qaD in longhand. (It is non-canon, of course – and to my knowledge not endorsed by the KLI.)

It was 20 years ago, I've seen it, and I don't remember it. (I do remember not liking it. ;^)